# What does 来 mean in 他想一切办法来验证这个理论 and 我们设了个陷阱来抓狐狸?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I have come across two sentences independently which seem to use 来 in a similar fashion, but one I am not sure I can identify:

他想一切办法**来**验证这个理论

我们设了个陷阱**来**抓狐狸

Is this somewhat similar to 起来, as in describing a resultative state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Using "lai" to connect two verb phrases](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Using_%22lai%22_to_connect_two_verb_phrases)

> The word 来 (lái) can be used to connect two verb phrases, relating the actions to each other. It can be translated as "in order to" or "so that," and it can help in explaining reasoning.

Comment: This reminds me of my other question here: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36850/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-%e6%9d%a5-to-convey-the-meaning-in-order-to?noredirect=1#comment54469_36850

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite:

他想尽一切办法来验证这个理论。

as

他为了验证这个理论想尽一切办法。

and

我们为了抓住狐狸设了个陷阱。

as

我们设了个陷阱来抓住狐狸。

So, this 来 and 为了 seem to be quite similar here.